# What is this power wire called?

Tags: wire

It is shielded flexible multistrand power wire with silicone insulation, like some hobby drones use. May be it has some specific name?

[image]

Comment: Well "anywhere" can't be everywhere else you would find it. Shopping questions are off-topic BTW.

Comment: Asking what it is (proper name to search for it yourself) is cool.  Asking where to buy it ain't.

Comment: Great comments. I am asking what it is called, not if its cool or not ;)

Comment: You're not being downvoted because you haven't searched (I'm sure you have). You're being downvoted because you're asking where to get them, which is off topic for this site and is not allowed.

Comment: I would suggest to look for a shielded single strand wire. Obviously, there are a lot of choices and you just have to find one that meets your requirements. And this is not a coaxial cable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "Shielded Security Cable". Use this keyword to search for it online. You will surely get multiple results from different vendors. A nearby Home Depot would be a good place to find it assuming you live in USA.

Comment: Dear friend. Thanks for the answer. There are plenty of cables there, but nothing like the one I needed.